# How do i solve this gas out of limit issue?

Tags: go-ethereum

From:        0x08393207d999c507670510ea5713d4842ecfc86e
To Contract: 0x9a4bdb797d957be02804410ec49cd6de4a831b9d
 Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]

[image]

Comment: did you try to increase the gas limit ???

Comment: But I'm through the trading platform send to another trading platform ,so  i need how to increase the gas limit ?

Comment: every instruction cost some amount of Gas, you should now how much does your contract needs when you compile it, the compiler should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the gas limit.  In the image you posted, you've set the gas limit to `21,000` which is the minimum cost of any transaction.  For instance just sending value costs `21,000`.

Deploying any contract will cost more.

In whatever "trading platform" you are using, there should be a way to increase the gas limit.

Comment: So which trading platform do I need find them to solve?  sender exchange address or  receive exchange address ?